# Displaying a Loading Bar with RTL support

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I'm trying to add the RTL support to my React Application.

Since I'm using a loading bar ([this one : react-redux-loading-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-loading-bar)) when making calls to APIs, long process ... I want also to change it to be from Right to Left also when RTL is active.

I tried to use Material UI [Progress Bar](https://material-ui.com/components/progress/#linear-indeterminate) first but I didn't found a good examples / ideas to how can I add it into my workflow which is just : React / Redux. This could solve the problem also.

Is there any solution to achieve that ?

My Redux Action look like this :

```
export const rdxDoGetCategories = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      showLoadingBar(dispatch); // Show loading bar
      dispatch(rdxGetCategories(await getCategories())); // Call to the API then save it into the store
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
    } finally {
      hideLoadingBar(dispatch); // Hide loading bar
    }
  };
};
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: showLoadingBar(dispatch)  should be dispatch(showLoadingBar(true)) same thing should apply for hideLoadingBar.  : https://github.com/mironov/react-redux-loading-bar#usage-without-middleware

Comment: Hey @Ashish , hideLoadingBar and showLoadingBar are both two internal functions, contains dispatch(showLoading()), dispatch(hideLoading()) and other logic. In the LTR version the Loading Bar is working as expected. However if I switch to the RTL version it double the width of the page and still go from left to right. And this is what I'm asking about.
Thanks for your time !